# How to remove a pip package installed with sudo -h

Tags: command-line, python, sudo, pip

My question is quite simple:
I've installed virtualenv with the following command:

```
sudo  -H pip3 install virtualenv
```

It seems to be wrong, because in the tutorial that I watch pip downloads other stuff than on my pc.
**How can I undo it?**
Thx for your help and stay healthy!

Comment: This was duped to [How do I detect and remove Python packages installed via pip?](https://askubuntu.com/q/173323) and [Trying to create a python virtual environment but getting OSError](https://askubuntu.com/q/400343), but it doesn't seem to be a duplicate of either. The first is about finding what Python packages to remove and removing multiple packages; this is about removing one, whose name is known. Also, `pip` and `pip3` aren't equivalent on most Ubuntu systems. The second one is about doing something very different that *happens to involve* a command, as its first step, that solves this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was as simple as the question.

```
pip3 uninstall virutalenv
```

did the job